# How template synchronization works in Expression engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine, php-5.3

i want to use template synchronization for subscription add on testing but when i clicked on template synchronization its not showing anything. i have copied two templates to template folder as you can see in documentation [here](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/subscriptions/)

**Things I have done for this in Global preference are :-**

1. Save Template Revisions: `Yes`
2. Maximum Number of Revisions to Keep: `10`
3. Save Template Revisions: `Yes`
4. Server path to site's templates: `example.com/system/expressionengine/templates`

Please tell me if anything else wrong or required.

Comment: Duplicate question on StackOverflow ExpressionEngine site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34353/how-template-synchronization-works-in-expression-engine/34354#34354

Comment: @abhaystacks you should not be posting the same question on two different SE sites at nearly the same time, nor should you be using two different logins on the sites

Comment: @AllInOne Stackoverflow is your website ?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization works something like this:

- When you do Editing in Files from FTP, It modifies files only. But backup of all template files are saves in EE database.
- Synchronization just copy the content of that file and put it in database.
- You must need proper permission in templates folder to do Synchronization. Permissions should be 775 or 777

I hope that makes sense.